# Linear layout not clickable after first layout

Tags: android, layout

### Linear Layout

I am trying to create a `LinearLayout` on the main screen to act as a menu.  I didn't want `Buttons` or have to create images, I like the look I get with the `TextViews` and `Layouts`.  My problem is I cannot get the `onClick()` to work past the first layout, its been driving me nuts the past couple days.  Is there something small I'm missing or am I doing it all wrong?

### Main.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            LinearLayout computer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_btn_computer);
            LinearLayout networking = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_btn_networking);

            computer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
              //Call your method here
                          startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ComputerMain.class));        
                      }

            });

          networking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
              //Call your method here 
                          startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetworkingMain.class));  
                      }

            });
          }
    }
    }
```

### Main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dip" >





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_btn_computer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Operating Systems"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Windows, Linux, Dos, and Mac"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_font" />

        </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_btn_networking"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Networking"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cisco, HP Procurve"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_font" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Creating 2 `TextView`s with same `id`?!! One more thing, `android:onClick="onClickFeature"` is only used for `RelativeLayout`, so remove it too.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using `onClickFeature(View v)` it's `onClick(View v)`.

are setting your `onClickListener()`?

Comment: I was using onClickFeature(View v) when I had buttons and set the onClick attribute of the button to use it.

Comment: @A.A: `android:onClick="onClickFeature"`, you should look carefully! He is right!

Answer (score 0):

Call your `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout computer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_btn_computer);
LinearLayout networking = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_btn_networking);
```

Set the onClick Listeners

```
computer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //Call your method here
                startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ComputerMain.class));        
            }

  });

networking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //Call your method here 
                startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetworkingMain.class));  
            }

  });
```

Remove the `android:onClick=""` attributes

Comment: I updated the code; I still can't get it to work, not sure what I am missing.